# _layouts/cp.twig cannot be found

Tags: craft3, control-panel, modules, craft4

I have a module that's meant to add a section to the CP.

```
class Reports extends Module
{
    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        Event::on(
            Cp::class,
            Cp::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_NAV_ITEMS,
            function (RegisterCpNavItemsEvent $event) {
                $event->navItems[] = [
                    'url' => 'reports',
                    'label' => 'Reports',
                    //'icon' => '@mynamespace/path/to/icon.svg',
                    'subnav' => [
                        'vat' => ['label' => 'VAT', 'url' => 'reports/vat']
                    ],
                ];
            }
        );

        Event::on(
            View::class,
            View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS,
            function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $event) {
                $event->roots['reports'] = __DIR__ . '/templates';
            }
        );

    }
}
```

Inside of my module is a templates folder, and the templates are being reached, however the `{% extends "_layouts/cp.twig" %}` is erroring from my template files. This is index.twig:

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp.twig" %}
{% set title = "Reports" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Reports</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and this is the error:
[image]

The code is straight from Craft 4.x and 3.x Docs (same for both), so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ONE tiny difference between Craft 3.x and Craft 4.x!

`{% extends "_layouts/cp.html" %}` for Craft 3

`{% extends "_layouts/cp.twig" %}` for Craft 4

and to avoid a future breakage on update, I did find that
`{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}` works for both.